# Normalised APSD

Tags: power-spectral-density

How you compute the Normalised APSD of a signal using python's scipy.signal libary. Do you compute only the APSD of the signal and divide it by (PSD * df) or there is something else?

Comment: huh! I've seen CPSD (cross-power spectral density), I've not seen APSD. CPSD is defined as the Fourier transform of the *cross-correlation function* between two signals. Assuming A in APSD is for "auto": how does APSD differ from PSD? What's its definition?

Comment: you are right, by apsd  i mean the CPSD of the signal with itself. If i want to normalise the result how should i do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd assume you'd divide each PSD value by the square root of the signal energy, thereby bringing the energy to 1.

Energy is the sum of all squares.